# SSH connection refused with DNS

Tags: ssh, dns, raspberry-pi

I have searched and I know people have asked this before, but I have been through all settings and double, triple checked everything but I can't get it to work for the life of me. I have not this before with other machines, but I don't know why this isn't working.
*note: numbers have been changed for security reasons
Here is what I have:

**Client**
Raspberry Pi 3 with IP: 192.168.0.133
manual port in raspberry pi 3 sshd_config file: 1502

**Router:**
NAT Virtual Server:
External port: 1502
Internal port: 22
IP address: 192.168.0.133

**DNS(duckdns.org)**
- checked to make sure public IP address points to the domain: testing2@duckdns.org

*ssh command that works on client:*
ssh -p 1502 client@192.168.0.133

*ssh command that doesn't work*
ssh -p 1502 client@testing2.duckdns.org

So I'm not sure where it's going on. here is output from ssh -v -p 1502 client@testing2.duckdns.org

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/testing/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to testing2.duckdns.org [188.45.22.61] port 1502.
debug1: connect to address 188.45.22.61 port 1502: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host testing2.duckdns.org port 1502: Connection refused
```

Any ideas? I really would appreciate any insights.

EDIT: To add some more clarifying information:
When I run the second command listed above, that is failing:
ssh -p 1502 client@testing2.duckdns.org

This goes out to the DNS I have setup (testing2.duckdns.org) and that DNS points to my network's public facing IP address. At that point, it hits the NAT routing rule I have setup on my router that forwards any requests from port 1502 to the internal port of 22 to the IP address of 192.168.0.133.

This is why I don't understand where it is failing, all the rules are there and the route should be open. Is there a setting on the raspberry pi (within the config file) that I'm missing?

Comment: You configured your SSH server to listening on port 1502, but configured your router to forward traffice to port 22.

Comment: no the external port is set to:1502 and the internal port is: 22. I have the exact same settings (as far as having the port forwards in the correct fields) for another port forward that works just fine. I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: In the first (successful) command, you are connecting to private IP, in the second one you are trying to connect to public IP.

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DusanBajic I have the "testing2.duckdns.org" forward to my public facing IP address of my network. This is necessary instead of having to input a public facing IP address. I don't know if this is what you are referring to, but that is how I understand it works. I will add some language above to clarify

Comment: But are you trying to connect from within your private network?

Comment: Yes. I have also tested from outside my local network and that also fails with the same error. The strange thing is, I have an almost identical setup connecting to a NAS within my network, and that connects just fine (going through a different DNS address and internal IP obviously).

Comment: Somethin does not add up: how can `ssh -p 1502 client@192.168.0.133` work, if the internal port is 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was going on, and although I am still not able to connect remotely, I have solved what the original question posed.

The problem was I had changed the port on the raspberry pi (the internal port) to 1502. This meant that the route was forwarding correctly (from external of 1502 to internal of 22) but then the internal port was set to 1502, so it failed to connect.

This also explains why it would connect locally with the above command because the local port was 1502.

I still can't connect remotely because the raspberry pi is running a VPN and this is causing the SSH request to timeout, but that is a separate question.

Thanks for the help everyone!